# Как получить читаемый JSON из тела ответа?

Tags: json, парсер, golang, web-scraping

Отправляю POST через go-colly, On.Response отдает тело ответа, но отдает его в нечитаемом формате, пытался сделать через JSON Unmarshal не получилось.

```
func Sub(c *colly.Collector) string {
    var profile int
    profile = 2
    err := c.Post(subLink, map[string]string{"userId": strconv.Itoa(profile)})
    c.OnResponse(func(r *colly.Response) {
        fmt.Println("response received, ", r.Body)
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Erorr: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("req send")
    return "done"
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос подробности. Во-первых, что напечатает ваша программа, если в `OnResponse` напечатать строковое представление `fmt.Println("response received, ", string(r.Body))`? Как именно вы вызывали `json.Unmarshal`? Какую ошибку возвращала эта функция?

Comment: В представленном коде [tag:json] нигде не используется. Необходимо уточнить вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю за вашу библиотеку, но вот парсинг body:

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body) 
if err != ... 
defer r.Body.Close() 

err := json.Unmarshal(body, &myObject) 
if err !=
```

Вместо myObject подставьте экземпляр своей структуры, куда будете парсить json